# is it possible to define user-defined variable in visual studio debug window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

For example, I want to check the following expression in debug watch window:

```
((MyClass1*)0xc56fbf0)->m_data1->m_data2
```

Is it possible to write something like:

```
v=0xc56fbf0
((MyClass1*)v)->m_data1->m_data2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is not possible in the C++ code (you CAN do that in C# by declaring new variable in the Intermediate window).

However, there is an easy work-around: you can declare one (or few?) global variable of the needed type; call it something like `WatchVar`, and use it as you wish.